# How to JPA-map a two classes to the same table differentiated by the type column and have them have a collection that is the rows of the table

Tags: java, jpa

Let's say I have this database table design (the key values have to be dynamic, so no, I can't turn them into separate columns or properties):

table house which consists of:

- id
- other properties that don't matter like name, etc

table house_properties which consists of:

- id
- house_id (fk pointing to house)
- type (enum('EXTERIOR', 'INTERIOR', ... other))
- key (string)
- value (string)

example data:

house:

- id = 1, name = "whatever"
- id = 2, name = "I don't care this is just example"

house_properties:

- id = 100, house_id = 1, type = EXTERIOR, key = 'roof', value = 'shingles'
- id = 101, house_id = 1, type = EXTERIOR, key = 'paint color', value = 'white'
- id = 102, house_id = 1, type = EXTERIOR, key = 'shutters', value = 'orange'
- id = 103, house_id = 1, type = INTERIOR, key = 'hallway wall color', value = 'green'
- id = 104, house_id = 1, type = INTERIOR, key = 'kitchen floor color', value = 'blue'
- id = 105, house_id = 1, type = INTERIOR, key = 'bathroom has mirror', value = 'false'

---

- id = 106, house_id = 2, type = EXTERIOR, key = 'roof', value = 'metal'
- id = 107, house_id = 2, type = EXTERIOR, key = 'walls', value = 'brick'
- id = 108, house_id = 2, type = EXTERIOR, key = 'windows', value = 'double glass'
- id = 109, house_id = 2, type = INTERIOR, key = 'wall color', value = 'red'
- id = 110, house_id = 2, type = INTERIOR, key = 'kitchen floor', value = 'lenolium'
- id = 110, house_id = 2, type = INTERIOR, key = 'bathroom has mirror', value = 'true'

I need to map the result properties table to multiple classes determined by the value of the table's "type" property. Each of the classes should contain a collection of key value pairs.

The house is pretty easy, but I'm trying to figure out the other two classes:

```
@Entity
public class House {

    Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house")
    Collection<ExteriorProperties> exteriorProperties;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house")
    Collection<InteriorProperties> interiorProperties;

    // ... more fields
    // ... getters setters

}

// SINGLE instance for ALL house_properties rows with the same house_id and type = "EXTERIOR"
// How to JPA-map this??
public class ExteriorProperties {

    Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    House house; // ref back to house 

    // the collection of key-value pairs that are in all rows with the same house_id and type = "EXTERIOR"
    // How to JPA map this???
    Map<String, String> properties;

    // ... getters, setters
}

// SINGLE instance for ALL house_properties rows with the same house_id and type = "INTERIOR"
// How to JPA-map this??
public class InteriorProperties {

    Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    House house; // ref back to house 

    // the collection of key-value pairs that are in all rows with the same house_id and type = "INTERIOR"
    // How to JPA map this???
    Map<String, String> properties;

    // ... getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Is the question about how to do inheritance in JPA? That should be straight forward, did you look/try?

Comment: No, that is not the question. Neither of those classes extend eachother....

Comment: Why not? They are identical other than the name. The table structure you describe is something JPA does with inheritance.